# SQL Query Optimization on joining 2 views

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I'm trying to join 2 views which have around 800k records. When I try to run the below query it really takes long time(more than 20 mins) to run..

So there are 2 views..

View A:

```
 colA  colB  colC
=====================  
valueA valueB valueC
```

View B:

```
colD  colE  colA
=====================  
valueD valueE valueA
```

need to join these 2 views on colA. SO the query I have used is:

```
select  
count(*)  
from  
   (  
     select   colA,  colB,  colC  
        from viewA a
     inner join   
        viewB b on a.colA=b.colA and a.colA in (select distinct colA from viewA) 
        and
         b.colA in (select distinct colA from viewB
   );
```

I need to get the count of the rows and as there are duplicates in the views I have used 'distinct' keyword.
Can you plz crct me and tell me why the query is taking so long time?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Comment: What is the point of the subqueris - `and a.colA in (select distinct colA from viewA)`?

Comment: There are duplicates of colA in each view I want to join only the distinct columns. @Alex

Comment: Having a DISTINCT in the SELECT for an IN condition will not do that though. IN(1, 2, 3) or IN(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2) mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: But every value in colA is in the subset of distinct values from that column. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to find how many distinct "colA" are in both views

```
select count(distinct a.colA)
from viewA a
inner join viewB b on a.colA = b.colA
```